# PowerApps How can I change the text in a textbox on the click of a button

Tags: powerapps

I'm trying to do a simple task of changing the text in a text box, on the click of a button in PowerApps.

I have a button "Button1" - and a textbox "TextInput2" on my page.

The buttons OnSelect action is set to: TextInput2.Text = "hello"

Nothing happens when I click the button. The textbox's text remains unchanged.

I also tried UpdateContext({TextInput2:"Hi"}) in the OnSelect action of the button.

Is there a way of doing this in PowerApps, that I may just be missing?

Thank you, Mark

Answer (score 4):

Finally getting my head around PowerApps.

Set the textbox's text property to:

```
If(HasBeenPressed, "Hello", "GoodBye")
```

Set the button's OnSelect event to:

```
UpdateContext({HasBeenPressed:true})
```

...and it's working.

I hope this helps others.

Comment: If you want to have fun and toggle the value, then for the button's OnSelect use `UpdateContext({HasBeenPressed:!HasBeenPressed})`

Comment: Looks like Text property is removed.